# Add classes to quick tabs and nested tabs within quick tabs

Tags: 7, blocks

How can I add custom css classes to quick tabs and nested tabs within quick tabs?

Comment: Why do you need additional classes, can you not target using .parent .child element CSS selectors?

Comment: I am using an instance of Quick Tabs within Quick Tabs so both the parent and the child are given the same class by Drupal.

Comment: Yes, but you can do things with CSS like `.quicktabs ul .quicktabs ul{ background-color:red } /* target child container */`

Comment: i tried...but the change is reflecting on all of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read this [issue](http://drupal.org/node/656330). Try to apply the [patch](http://drupal.org/files/add-custom-class-656330-6.patch) by using `git apply` command line :

```
$ git apply --directory=path/to/module-dir/ add-custom-class-656330-6.patch
```

If you don't use git, add this line in the `theme_qt_quicktabs_tabset` function near the **`line 589`** on the `quicktabs.module` file and the function will become :

```
<?php
function theme_qt_quicktabs_tabset($vars) {
   if ($key == $vars['tabset']['#options']['active']) {
     $item['class'] = array('active');
   }
   $item['class'][] = drupal_html_class($tab['#title']);# new line added by the patch
   $item['data'] = drupal_render($tab);
   $variables['items'][] = $item;
 }
?>
```

of course **WITHOUT** the `<?php ?>` tags

After that you have the title in class attributes :

**Example :**

- tab title => given tab title
- automatic tab class => given_tab_title

Wish helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the [Block Class](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_class) module. After enabling, you can add a class when configuring the block for the quicktabs instance, as well as any blocks included in your quicktabs instance.